# What happens to the Shield Gate in the Rogue One novel?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

How is the deflector shield above Scarif destroyed or temporarily disabled in the Rogue One novel? How are people able to pass through before the Death Star fires?

Comment: Possible dupe of [How would the shield gate have “regenerated”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148251/how-would-the-shield-gate-have-regenerated)

Comment: @Valorum I do not believe the question is a duplicate, however I do believe the answer to that question also answers this question

Comment: @Gandalf'sFISTS - That's the definition of a duplicate :-) The questions don't have to be identical. If the answer from one answers the other *without significant alteration*, it's still a dupe.

Comment: I find it interesting that OP is specifically asking about the novel though. Does anybody know if the novel deviates much from the movie in any way?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I've addressed that in my answer to the (possible) dupe